# I can't get variables with put method - xmlhttprequest - laravel

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, laravel-5, xmlhttprequest

I want to save my image data and I'm using XMLHttpRequest, I can send json data as well, I can see them on developer console (in parameters section). But when I can't use them on server side, `$request` seems null ?

Here is my javascript codes;

```
 document.querySelectorAll('.galeri-cart').forEach(function (image) {
    image.addEventListener('click',function () {

// update stuff

document.getElementById('submit_button').addEventListener('click',function () {
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
          token = document.head.querySelector("[name=csrf-token]").content;
      xhr.open('PUT','images/update/'+id,false);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN',token);
      xhr.onload = function () {
             swal("Updated successfully", {
                  icon: "success",
                    });

                   };
     let data = {};
         data.alt = altInput.value;
         data.url = urlInput.value;

     xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data))
              })
         })
     });
```

and here is in my controller;

```
public function updateMedia(Request $request, $id) {
   $image = Media::find($id);
   $image->image_alt_name = $request->input('alt');
   $image->image_path = $request->input('url');
   $image->save();

   return json_endcode($request);
    }
```

route; (this route under the images prefix)

```
Route::put('update/{id}',['as'=>'media.update','uses'=>'MediaController@updateMedia']);
```

So, do you have any advice ? What is my wrong in here ? And thanks four your help :)

Comment: Can we see your `web.php` file?

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL in the AJAX request is different from the one in the laravel route

```
AJAX ---> "images/update/"
Laravel Route ---> "update/"
```

Comment: I have images prefix

Comment: Your 'put' route is nested, Right? Why don't you try `$request()->json()->all();` in your controller instead of `$request->input()` so as to be able to see all your input.

Comment: hmm, then how to I use it in controller

Comment: First use a `var_dump` to see if the request has an output. `$request->json()->all()` produces an array output.In other words, you should have an output like this `["alt" =>"your_value", "url"=>"your_value"]`.

Comment: And also laravel has own dd() method for that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  xhr.open('PUT','images/update/'+id,false);
```

Your path contains an additional `images` whereas your `web.php` is only showing `/update/{id}` without `images`

Comment: I have "images" prefix